# Export the search results in .pdfs and Excel

Tags: oracle-adf

I have requirement to export search results in PDFs and Excel. Export is the command button is of drop down list PDFs and Excel how to achieve this.

I have already implemented by using report declarative component but its not take the data:

```
 <report:reportDeclarative ButtonName="Export"
                              IteratorName="#{bindings.MChecklistVO1Iterator}"
                              ReportName="Checklist Instruction Template"
                              ReportType="EXCEL,PDF" TableId="tt1" id="rd1"
                              SerialColumnHeader="#{ngb_bizfile_e_portalBundle.SERIAL_NO}"
                              rendered="#{pageFlowScope.checklistInstructionBean.searchDetailsRender}" Pagination="true"
                              SerialNumber="false"/>      
                              <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s3"/>
```

Comment: We will not do the work for you. Please show us what you have attempted so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a table or tree in your jsf page you can use Export Collection Action listener
 in your button